# Copying missing data between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table **Alpha**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | null |

I have a reference of table like **BETA** of one column
like

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

I want to copy the data missing in **Alpha**  with respect to **Beta** to another table **Gamma** such that

The expected result is  as follows

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |
| null | null | 5 |

It has to refer to the beta table as it is not always in order,
eg.  beta table can be 2,3,5 and alpha table has 2 and 3 so the missing value is just 5

PS: this is a minimal representation, in real there are more than 20 columns in **Alpha** but only one column in **beta**
The table **Alpha** and expected result table are same

Comment: So what have you tried and where are you stuck? One assumes you just need a simple `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I just wanted to know if we can insert with a condition.!?

Comment: Have you checked a tutorial and/or the official documentation? Its SQL 101...

Comment: If I am correct it is the update statement, but that is fine for 3 or 4 columns what if we have more than 50 columns, is there simpler way to do that

Comment: Thats not what you asked in your question? And yes, read the docs, there is only one insert statement, not matter how many columns...

Comment: I think I explained it wrong in the comments, the data that has to be present in **GAMMA** is the data that is not in **ALPHA** with respect to the data in **BETA**

Comment: Just a normal phenomenon seeing Mr Smart @DaleK doing nice thing to new contributor.

Comment: I dint know how to start, If someone could help me with how to approach it it would be helpful

Comment: Show us the table schema for `Alpha`, `Beta` & `Gamma`. Also sample data from these 3 tables and the expected result

Comment: @GunduMurugan if you don't know where to start you need a tutorial, not a question here. This is a site for answering specific technical issues you run into while attempting to solve your problem. Its not a site where we do it all for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to put my crystal ball into overdrive.

I think you wanted to generate the missing value for each column in table `Alpha` based on the list of value in table `Beta'

What the below query doing is find out the missing value for each column (`A`, `B`, `C`). After that `PIVOT` it

```
; with missing as
(
    select  col = 'A', V = A
    from    Beta b
    where   not exists (select  * from Alpha a where a.A = b.A)  

    union all

    select  col = 'B', V = A
    from    Beta b
    where   not exists (select * from Alpha a where a.B = b.A)  

    union all

    select  col = 'C', V = A
    from    Beta b
    where   not exists (select * from Alpha a where a.C = b.A)  
)
select  [A], [B], [C]
from    (
            select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by col order by V)
            from    missing
        ) m
        pivot
        (
            max(V)
            for col in ([A], [B], [C])
        ) p
```

PS : if you really have `50` columns in table `Alpha`, you need to do the `union all` query 50 times, each for one of the column.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use several insert statement for this problem

```
INSERT GAMMA(A)
SELECT BETA.a FROM BETA
LEFT JOIN ALPHA ON BETA.a = ALPHA.A
WHERE ALPHA.A IS NULL
```

Change the A to B or another column name.

But this table will produce table like this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | null | null |
| 5 | null | null |
| null | 1 | null |
| null | 2 | null |
| null | null | 2 |
| null | null | 4 |

This might not be the answer you want, but i hope it gives you alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but this is not the answer I was looking for

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think GAMMA table shouldn't be designed that way. I just misstype in my first answer, and have edited it

Comment: @GunduMurugan if you tried that (or anything), show us what you tried in your question to avoid exactly this case where you get offered the same answer you have already tried.

Comment: But GAMMA should be the table that contains the missing values of all columns in ALPHA